# Visibility hidden not working until mouse is moved

Tags: html, css

`visibility: hidden` is not working until the mouse is moved.

```js
const link = document.getElementById("link");

      link.onclick = (event) => {
        link.style.visibility = "hidden";
        link.style.pointerEvents = "none";

        event.preventDefault();
      };
```

```html
<a id="link" href="http://localhost">home</a>
```

I need the `#link` to stop being hovered with CSS.

If I click `#link` and I don't move the mouse, the link is still hovered (the cursor is pointer and the link appears on the bottom).

If I apply `display: none` it will work but I don't want to use that because I could use `transition` and `opacity`.

Comment: Consider not using an anchor element if you don't want it to behave like an anchor? Also not reproducible on Firefox

Comment: Hi @DarkBee , it's a little example taken from a bigger markup. I'm testing on Chrome 116.

Comment: I don't see this problem on Edge/Chrome or Firefox on WIndows10. What OS are you on? Also what debugging have you tried (e.g. console log when enter and leaving the event handler).

Comment: @AHaworth It's a little bit hard to find. You have to make sure that you don't move the mouse while clicking the link. I wasn't using JS for debugging, just looking at the cursor, if it's `pointer`, it's still hovered. However, I have found a fix. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to add `opacity: 0` next to `visibility`.

```
link.onclick = (event) => {
  link.style.visibility = "hidden";
  link.style.opacity = 0;

  event.preventDefault();
};
```

Update:

In this example, the `onclick` handler sets the opacity to 0 and visibility to hidden when the element is clicked.

If you only use visibility: hidden, the element remains in its hover state until you move the mouse away because it's technically still there but just invisible. Adding opacity: 0 ensures that it's fully hidden and won't trigger any hover effects.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).